# best option for console i/o in dll

Tags: c, windows, dll, console, printf

I have a C-based program (a 64bit multithreaded console app using VS2010) that now must be turned into a dll.  Having never worked with a dll, I am trying to figure out the best way to get data to/from the console.  The i/o is nothing complex: get a string, print a string:

```
while (1)
{
    printf(" Enter next data _ ");
    char input[500];
    gets(input);
    if (input[0] == '!')
       break;
    doSomething(input);
}
```

It seems that there are a few options, eg, allocConsole, popen, getStdOut, etc that I've started to explore, but before I get too deep into this forest, is there a simpler, more straightforward approach?  Would the whole thing be easier if I called the DLL from a small Windows app (as opposed to a console app)?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a dll *will* write to stdout when the exe and dll are both console apps....